# using knockout es5 plugin in AMD module

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, dojo

I can use knockout with requirejs applications AMD module, [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html) example. Actually using dojo toolkit.

```
// Main viewmodel class
define(['knockout-x.y.z'], function(ko) {
    return function appViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable('Bert');
    };
});
```

But how can I use knockoutjs extension **knockout-es5** this is does not work in AMD module.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, knockout-es5 is not an AMD-compliant module. However, that doesn't stop you from using it properly with RequireJS. What you will have to do is use a shim (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) in your require config. The reason you need this is because you need to tell require that the plugin depends on Knockout and therefore cannot be loaded first.

Here is what your require config might look like:

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        'ko': 'knockout.min',
        'koES5': 'knockout-es5.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'koES5': { deps: ['ko'] }
    }
};
```

This creates 2 paths, one to Knockout and one to Knockout-es5. In the shim we tell require that knockout-es5 depends on knockout. This ensures loading happens in the right order.

Now your RequireJS module you should look like:

```
define(['ko', 'koES5'], function(ko) {
    return function appViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable('Bert');
    };
});
```

NOTE: You technically don't need ko as a requirement because koES5 will already have asked it to load since it is marked as a dependency. Also, you don't need a variable for koES5 because it doesn't return anything that you would use, you're simply adding it as a requirement to ensure the file gets loaded.

Comment: sorry I edited post, I am using dojo toolkit. It did not work with dojo.